# twilio cobversations 3.1 delivery receipts or status of message in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, chat, twilio-conversations

Twilio Conversations Version 3.1

How i can get status of TCHMessage, to show it as seen, delivered or failed. I need to show single/double tick based on message status. I have reviewed all classes and library but not found solution on this for iOS Swift.

I have tried with getDetailedDeliveryReceipts callback but i m not receiving any value or respond from this too. Please help me out. I m expecting a call back where i can receive status of message whether delivered, failed or sent.

```
message.getDetailedDeliveryReceipts(completion: { result, detailedDeliveryReceipts in
            if let error = result.error {
                // Handle the error
                print("Error retrieving delivery receipts: \(error)")
            } else {
                print(message.aggregatedDeliveryReceipt)
                if let receipts = detailedDeliveryReceipts {
                    // Process the delivery receipts
                    for receipt in receipts {
                        let messageSID = receipt.messageSid
                        let messageStatus = receipt.status
                        
                        print("Message SID: \(messageSID ?? "")")
                        print("Message Status: \(messageStatus)")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```